# Why is my string comparison failing when checking against class names?

Tags: android, string, similarity

I'm working on a portion of an application which creates a user object on a server via HTTP POST. I'm having a really frustrating issue with matching the name of the callback class against a string constant.

#### Context:

Since this application makes about 8-10 different server requests, I've tried to encapsulate the actual connection process into one class, `HTTPConnection`. Every activity which needs to connect to the server passes its own instance of `AndroidHttpClient`, `HttpRequest`, and `HTTPConnectionListener`, which is an interface which every calling activity implements which allows the server response to be sent directly back to the activity.

This has been working great until I had to implement a portion of the app which required a response *header* to be returned. Until this point, I've only had to deal with response *bodies*, so  `HTTPConnection` only returned the body. To solve this, **I rewrote `HTTPConnection` to check the name of the callback class, then return the header or body depending on which class was requesting the data.**

What seemed like an easy solution has now used a good portion of my morning, so I realized I needed more eyes to see what I'm doing wrong.

#### The Problem:

In the constructor of `HTTPConnection`, I store the callbackListener (which is really anything that implements `HTTPConnectionListener`). In this case, my calling activity `EditAccountActivity` is the callback. I save this in a field early in doInBackground() to check against later.

```
    String callbackName = callbackListener.getClass().toString(); // Get the full name of the callback class and store it here. 
    Log.v(TAG, "** Callback listener is set to " + callbackName);
```

Then, after I have finished the connection, I want to check against a constant (eventually a list of constants) to determine whether or not I return the body or the header of the response.

```
// The constant I am trying to match
final protected String EDIT_ACCOUNT = "com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity";
```

The logic of returning the body or response is below.

```
// Determine which section of response to return
if (callbackName.equals(EDIT_ACCOUNT)) {
    Header responseHeader = response.getFirstHeader("Location");
    return responseHeader.getValue();
} else {
return serverResponse;
}
```

As you can tell by the ridiculous amount of Log statements, I've been debugging with no success. My logcat output looks like this.

```
07-10 12:44:54.932: INFO/com.example.appname.ServerFetcher(21650): Entity set: HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE - application/json
07-10 12:44:54.932: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.ServerFetcher(21650): Sending user json:     {"last_name":"tester ","first_name":"tester       ","username":"test@testing11.com","password":"oflndveledmenkddjevhhlkh","email":"test@testing.com","profession":"tester "}
07-10 12:44:54.952: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): ** Callback listener is set to class com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity
07-10 12:44:54.952: INFO/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Executing the HTTP POST request to <url>
07-10 12:44:55.713: INFO/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): ** HTTP Response returned: 201 - CREATED
07-10 12:44:55.713: INFO/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): ** 201 - CREATED
07-10 12:44:55.713: INFO/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Response body:
07-10 12:44:55.713: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Callback name is class com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity
07-10 12:44:55.713: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Listener is class com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity
07-10 12:44:55.713: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Are they equal? true
07-10 12:44:55.713: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): EDIT_ACCOUNT constant is com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity
07-10 12:44:55.713: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Is callbackName equal to EDIT_ACCOUNT? false
07-10 12:44:55.713: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.HTTPConnection(21650): Is callbackListener.getClass().toString() equal to EDIT_ACCOUNT? false
07-10 12:44:55.723: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity(21650): onConnectionFinish called.
07-10 12:44:55.743: VERBOSE/com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity(21650): Response returned from user creation is
```

**For some reason, whenever I check the class name of the *listener* with EDIT_ACCOUNT, it's not equal. But when I check the output, they all look equal to me. I'm not comparing anything with `==`, everything is checked using `.equals()`.** As a result, the body of the if statement is never executed, which means I output an empty string (as there is no response body in this particular connection).

Any advice on how to proceed would help keep hair on my head. Here's the whole class if needed.

#### HTTPConnection.java

```
package com.example.appname;

public class HTTPConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

final protected String TAG = HTTPConnection.class.getName();
protected AndroidHttpClient httpClient;
protected HttpRequestBase httpRequest;
protected HTTPConnectionListener callbackListener;

// Callback Class Name Constants
final protected String EDIT_ACCOUNT = "com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity"; 

public HTTPConnection(AndroidHttpClient httpClient, HttpRequestBase httpRequest, HTTPConnectionListener listener) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
    this.callbackListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void.. voids) {
    String serverResponse = null;
    String callbackName = callbackListener.getClass().toString(); // Get the full name of the callback class and store it here. 
    Log.v(TAG, "** Callback listener is set to " + callbackName);

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing the HTTP " + httpRequest.getMethod() + " request to " + httpRequest.getURI().toString());
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

        // Grab the returned string as it is returned and make it a String to save memory.
        StringBuilder stringBuilderResponse = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        serverResponse = stringBuilderResponse.toString();

        // Log the response.
        Log.i(TAG, "** HTTP Response returned: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " - " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        Log.i(TAG, "** Response Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " Reason Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        Log.i(TAG, "Response body: " + serverResponse);

        // ** Debug string equality **
        Log.v(TAG, "Callback name is " + callbackName);
        Log.v(TAG, "Listener is " + callbackListener.getClass().toString());
        boolean equality1 = callbackName.equals(callbackListener.getClass().toString());
        Log.v(TAG, "Are they equal? " + equality1);
        Log.v(TAG, "EDIT_ACCOUNT constant is " + EDIT_ACCOUNT);
        boolean equality2 = callbackName.equals(EDIT_ACCOUNT);
        Log.v(TAG, "Is callbackName equal to EDIT_ACCOUNT? " + equality2);
        boolean equality3 = callbackListener.getClass().toString().equals(EDIT_ACCOUNT);
        Log.v(TAG, "Is callbackListener.getClass().toString() equal to EDIT_ACCOUNT? " + equality3);

        // Determine which section of response to return
        if (callbackName.equals(EDIT_ACCOUNT)) {
            Header responseHeader = response.getFirstHeader("Location");
            return responseHeader.getValue();
        } else {
        return serverResponse;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error when executing HTTP " + httpRequest.getMethod() + " request!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return serverResponse;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    httpClient.close();
    callbackListener.onConnectionFinish(result);
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callback name is ***class com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity***

EDIT_ACCOUNT constant is ***com.example.appname.EditAccountActivity***

*To fix this, instead of using callbackListener.getClass().toString() use callbackListener.getClass().getName(). – kabuko*

Comment: To fix this, instead of using `callbackListener.getClass().toString()` use `callbackListener.getClass().getName()`.